# log4net - One logger, multiple appenders

Tags: logging, signalr, log4net, log4net-configuration

I have an existing application, that logs all the information I need currently to log files (log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender)

```
public static readonly ILog GeneralLogger = LogManager.GetLogger("GeneralLogger");
```

Used in code as below:

```
GeneralLogger.Info("A log entry");
```

Now I want, without changing my application code, to add another appender to send those same log entries, at the same time, to SignalR (log4net.SignalR.SignalrAppender)

I thought I'd give it a try by doing the following:

```
<log4net>
    <appender name="GeneralLogAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
      <file value="logs\general_" />
      <appendToFile value="true" />
      <staticLogFileName value="false" />
      <rollingStyle value="Date" />
      <datePattern value="yyyyMMdd'.log'" />
      <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level - %message%newline" />
      </layout>
    </appender>

    <appender name="GeneralLogSignalRAppender" type="log4net.SignalR.SignalrAppender, log4net.SignalR">
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
            <conversionPattern value="%date %-5level - %message%newline" />
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <logger name="GeneralLogger">
        <level value="ALL" />
        <appender-ref ref="GeneralLogAppender" />
        <appender-ref ref="GeneralLogSignalRAppender" />
    </logger>
</log4net>
```

But I am not getting any data logging to SignalR? Can someone tell me if at least this part of my configuration is correct (with respect to adding multiple log appenders)

Thanks

Comment: Yes, looks good, both appenders are named correctly in the logger. If it's not working still, [enable internal debugging](http://haacked.com/archive/2006/09/27/Log4Net_Troubleshooting.aspx/) and check the log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**RESOLVED**

The config above is indeed correct. Good to note for future use :)

It turns out that the reason for the failing logging was the appender I was using (the **log4net.SignalR appender** by Chris Fulstow and/or Matthew Steeples, there are two the same, even in Nuget!) - it had a number of tweaks required before it would work correctly and very little documentation.

If anyone needs help with this I'd be glad to assist.